# SQL Grouping in one level, having in another level

Tags: sql

using any SQL engine (SQL server / Teradata) I need to do the following:

I have this table:

```
Class | sub class | student | income
```

So I need to group by Class and subclass, having sum(income) > 10. BUT I need to display the students that are in that class and subclass. (so I can't force to do a query in the where clause... because it has two fields)

Comment: I don't have much of a clue, but if you show us some sample data and your expected output, that would be helpful.

Comment: Also tag the DBMS you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding about your problem is correct, then following should work in Oracle. In case of MS-SQL, replace || with database specific concatenation operator.

```
SELECT 
     CLASS, SUBCLASS, STUDENT
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE 
    CLASS||SUBCLASS 
IN (
    SELECT 
         CLASS||SUBCLASS 
    FROM 
         (SELECT 
                CLASS, SUBCLASS, SUM(INCOME) 
          FROM 
                MYTABLE 
          WHERE 
                SUM(INCOME)>10)
          )
    )
```

Comment: This solved the problem! tks! i havent thought on concatetating :)